# unable to get JSON object from a web URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to access the JSON object from [this](https://matchstat.com/tennis/match-stats/m/8348298) third party service, inside my javascript application.

However, because I was getting the Same Origin Policy error earlier, I have tried using JSONP and jQuery and AJAX, respectively as follows.

Using JSONP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function foo(data)
    {
        // do stuff with JSON
        console.log(data);
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://matchstat.com/tennis/match-stats/m/8348298?callback=foo'

    document.body.appendChild(script);
    // or document.head.appendChild(script) in modern browsers
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getJSON("https://matchstat.com/tennis/match-stats/m/8348298?callback=?", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        // Get the element with id summary and set the inner text to the result.
        $('#summary').text(data.result);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    CallURL();

    function CallURL(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://matchstat.com/tennis/match-stats/m/8348298',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async:false,
            success: function (msg) {
                JsonpCallback(msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                ErrorFunction();
            }

        });

    }

    function JsonpCallback(json)
    {
        console.log("came inside JsonpCallback ...");
        document.getElementById('summary').innerHtml=json.result;
    }

    function ErrorFunction()
    {
        console.log("came inside the ErrorFunction() ...");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I haven't been able to access the JSON object.

Comment: You cannot just change the request type to JSONP, the response has to be formatted correctly for that to work which depends on the server. If you're getting SOP errors from the request using JSON, then the receiving domain has not enabled third-party requests through JS and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: ^ that, if the service doesn't specifically support JSONP, there's nothing you can do

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks. So, how do you suggest that I read json data from this URL ? Using server side PHP as an AJAX call?